# Armazenar uma variavel para utilizar fora da function

Tags: javascript

escrevi o seguinte codigo

```
app.post("/Dialogflow", function(request, response) { 
  
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST, 
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER, 
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS, 
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DB 
  }); 
  connection.connect();
  
  var intentName = request.body.queryResult.intent.displayName;

  else if(intentName == 'psqcont'){ 
    console.log('Pesquisar Contato');
    var TelefoneContato = request.body.queryResult.parameters['Celular'];
    var query = 'select * from Clientes where Celular = "'+TelefoneContato+'"';
    connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields) {
    var Endereco = results[0].endereco
      try{
            if (error) throw error;
            connection.end();
            if(TelefoneContato == results[0].Celular){
        var contato = ''; contato = '‍♂️Ola '+results[0].Nome+"\n"
          +'Digite *1* para pedir no restaurante ️'+'\n'
          +'Ou *2* para pedidos na loja ';
        response.json({"fulfillmentText": contato })
      }
      
      else{
        if (error) throw error;
        connection.end();
        var tchauresp = ''; tchauresp = 'Não achamos seu cadastro!';
        response.json({"fulfillmentText": tchauresp})
      }}
      catch(e){
        var tchauresp = ''; tchauresp = '‍♂️Opa! Vimos que seu numero não está cadastrado'
          +"\n"+
          'Por favor digite *3* para realizar o cadastro';
        response.json({"fulfillmentText": tchauresp})
        
      }
    });
  }
  
  else if(intentName == 'psqcont - 1 rest'){
    response.json({"fulfillmentText":'Para entrega, digite *1*, e para retirada digite *2*'})
    }
  
  else if(intentName == 'psqcont - 1 entrega'){
    console.log('Pesquisar Endereço');
      var respEnd = '', respEnd = "Confira se o endereço abaixo será o mesmo da entrega:"+
                                "Endereço: "+Endereco+
                                "Complemento: "
    response.json({"fulfillmentText": respEnd })
  

    }
  
 }
);
```

Não estou conseguindo utilizar a `var Endereco` do `else if(intentName == 'psqcont')`
dentro da `else if(intentName == 'psqcont - 1 entrega')`
ja tentei dar return
já tentei transformar a var Endereco em global, porém não tive sucesso
se alguem souber uma forma de fazer a var Endereco ficar global
ou se alguém puder apontar meu erro ajudaria muito.

Comment: pra declarar uma variável global, se não me engano, não precisa usar o var. apenas use endereço = true; ao invés de var endereço = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para vc usar um valor de uma variável de uma função fora dela, vc precisa retornar um valor usando:

```
function MyFunction(){
 var Endereco = true; 
 return Endereco; //essa variavel estará disponivel fora dessa função.
}
```

Para acessar essa variável fora dela, faça o seguinte:

```
function NovaFunction (){

 var teste = MyFunction(); // onde MyFunction() trará o valor de retorno.
 alert(teste); // true
}
```

Comment: Em `function NovaFunction()`
está dando `'MyFunction' is not defined`

Comment: @JoabeFerri esse código aqui funciona sem problemas. De qualquer forma tente declarar Endereco globalmente, sem o var e teste novamente. Mas deveria funcionar sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction () {
    function exp(){
            endereco = true 
            return endereco 
    }
    exp()
    return endereco
}
```

se você fizer uma função que retorne apenas essa variável e depois chamar, ela fica em escopo global , portanto que você chame a função

de forma mais otimizada esse codigo ficaria assim:

```
(function myFunction () {
            endereco = true 
})()

console.log(endereco)
```

> sem console.log